# div not streaching to the very top of the body

Tags: html, css

Here's my code:

```css
html,body, #main_div{
   height: 100%;
}
        body {
      background-color: #1862A1;
      background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #1862A1, #8529B1);
      padding-left: 20%;
      padding-right: 20%;
    }
        #main_div{
      background-color: white;
    buttom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
        }
```

My website only has a `<body>` tag in its masterpage and a centered `<div>` in my home page,
the problem is that the div doesn't stretch to the top of the body as seen in the picture:
[image]

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Oh, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`body` margin and padding `0` will solve the issue. So your updated code will be

```css
html,body, #main_div{
   height: 100%;
}
        body {
      background-color: #1862A1;
      background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #1862A1, #8529B1);
      padding-left: 20%;
      padding-right: 20%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
        #main_div{
      background-color: white;
    buttom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
        }
```